# Catchment area map automatic creation

Tags: borders, catchment-area

I want to create a map that shows the catchment area of download mirrors. What I found so far is only a manual option where you have to draw an area around that point. But I don't know exactly where the boundaries are for the mirror, the algorithm always chooses the nearest one.
I created a draft, it would probably look something like this:
[image: draft]

I have not found a good way to create a map like this just by entering lat/long or the addresses of the servers and not manually drawing the affected areas.

Are there tools already out there that I missed?

Or how could I get at least some points of the border to draw the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to construct Voronoi polygons on the sphere.

Given a set of points, the Voronoi polygon of a point of the set is the polygon that contains an area where that point is the nearest point of the set.

There's code in various languages to do this, including python and javascript, for example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-geo-voronoi

http://py-sphere-voronoi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/voronoi_utility.html